# After removing the text area, not able to add again or add other options in a react app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On click on the `Text Area`, button should add relevant text area in a pag. By clicking on the `close` button, system should remove the added `textarea` in a React page. By default, the close button shouldn't display. In this example, system is adding the text area, but once it is removed, I am not able to add the textarea anymore. Could someone please advise the issue here.

CSB link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-currying-jojdhi?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const [multiInput, setMultiInput] = useState("");
  const [createCode, setCreateCode] = useState("");
  const [createImageTag, setImageTag] = useState("");
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const createCodeSection = () => {
    const newElement = React.createElement("blockquote", {
      contenteditable: "true",
      className: "codehighlight",
      name: "codesection" + new Date().getTime()
    });
    setCreateCode((createCode) => [...createCode, newElement]);
  };

  const createMultilineTextSection = () => {
    const newElement = React.createElement("textarea", {
      contenteditable: "true",
      className: "defaultTextArea",
      name: "textarea" + new Date().getTime()
    });
    setCreateCode((multiInput) => [...multiInput, newElement]);
  };

  const createImageSection = () => {
    const newElement = React.createElement("img", {
      key: "ele" + new Date().getTime()
    });
    setCreateCode((createImageTag) => [...createImageTag, newElement]);
  };


  const removeElement = () => {
    setVisible((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <div className="adminSection">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="logout"></div>
          <div className="createBlogSection">
            <div className="row">
              <button onClick={createMultilineTextSection}>Text Area</button>
              <button onClick={createCodeSection}>Code</button>
              <button>Image</button>
            </div>{" "}
            <br></br>
            <div className="row">
              <textarea className="defaultTextArea"></textarea>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <div className="row">
              {visible && <span className="dtextArea">{createCode}</span>}
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              {visible && (
                <div>
                  <span className="closeElement">
                    <button onClick={removeElement}>X</button>
                  </span>
                  <span>{multiInput}</span>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

//css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.adminSection {
  width: 100%;
}

.adminSection h1 {
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 550px !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.logout img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: -100px 50px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}

.createBlogSection {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(700px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 25px !important;
  margin: 100px 20px 10px 20px !important;
  /* border: solid 1px; */
  border-color: #e2e8f0;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.defaultTextArea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 40px;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.codehighlight {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #353232 !important;
}

.closeElement {
  margin-left: 320px;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of how you've put the added elements, use:

```
const removeElement = (index) => {
    const newElements = multiInput.filter((_, i) => i == index);
    setMultiInput(newElements);
};

// Inside "return" (createBlogSection div)
multiInput.map((_input, index)  => {
  <div key={index}>
    {_input}
    <span className="closeElement">
      <button onClick={removeElement(index)}>X</button>
    </span>
  </div>
})
```

**Edit:**
Add `const [multiInput, setMultiInput] = useState([]);` and instead of pushing new elements into separate variables add all into multiInput only. Using `setMultiInput(multiInput) => [...multiInput, newElement]);` in each case.

Comment: Sorry, getting an error after trying the same >>  Uncaught TypeError: multiInput.map is not a function
    at Admin (admin.js:68:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)

Comment: Updated the answer, try now

Comment: I have tried as suggested here >> https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-rui-dsel34?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Now I am unable to see close button and browser getting stuck, i think its going into recursive loop/ never ending one